# How to call and read response from web api

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-web-api

i am new in web api. sorry to ask very basic question. suppose this is my web api class structure

```
public class Person
{
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    public Person(string fn, string ln)
    {
        FirstName = fn;
        LastName = ln;
    }
}

public class Team
{
    string TeamName;
    Person TeamLeader;
    List<Person> TeamMembers;

    public Team(string name, Person lead, List<Person> members)
    {
        TeamName = name;
        TeamLeader = lead;
        TeamMembers = members;
    }
}

public class Response
{
    int ResponseCode;
    string ResponseMessage;
    object ResponsePayload;
    public Response(int code, string message, object payload)
    {
        ResponseCode = code;
        ResponseMessage = message;
        ResponsePayload = payload;
    }
}

public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    public Response Get()
    {
        Person tom = new Person("Tom", "Cruise");
        Response response = new Response(1, "It works!", tom);
        return response;
    }
}

public class TeamController : ApiController
{
    public Response Get()
    {
        Person tom = new Person("Tom", "Cruise");
        Person cindy = new Person("Cindy", "Cullen");
        Person jason = new Person("Jason","Lien");
        Team awesome = new Team("Awesome", jason, new List<Person>(){tom,cindy});
        Response response = new Response(1, "It works!", awesome);
        return response;
    }
}
```

now tell me how could i call `PersonController and TeamController Get` function from c# winform application and also pass data some time to web api function.

i am new in web api and i need to develop a web api which will run in a separate pc and that web api will be consume by several winform clients.

winform clients will send person and team data to web api which web api save the data into db and again some time  winform clients fetch data from web api. i am looking for a example which show me how to write code which will create interaction between winform client and web api.

when we send data from winform client to web api then do i need to prepare json string and send it to web api or it will be automatically done behind the scene ?

need little bit guide line. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice tutorial on how to use WebApi from non-mvc applications: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Take a look at the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client/), which helps with the content negotiation and JSON composing/parsing.

Comment: i need a tutorial which will show me how to pass user credential first time when winform client will call web api function. suppose web api has form authentication then how winform client pass user credential to web api and read auth cookie but from the next time winclient will not send credential but will send auth cookie to web api just for validation. please redirect me to a valid article. thanks

Comment: This sounds like it could help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: your link is not opening. if this is your link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195(v=vs.110).aspx then it is not speaking what i am looking for. i want web api with form auth and winform will consume it. after authenticate winform how winform can include form auth cookie for every subsequent request.